# Movement and sight

Tags: dnd-4e, movement, line-of-sight

A character has a light source on himself, in an otherwise dark area. She ventures in an enemy-ridden area, revealing the position and nature of some enemies as she moves.

How is this ruled?
Should she move square by square, telling at each square the direction she wants, until she wants to stop or she ends her movement?
Should she go on the path she traced before seeing the enemies, at least up to where she could see at the beginning of the round? What happens when she reaches that spot?

Comment: Also, what sort of light? 4e doesn't really handle "light ranges" much.

Comment: I have some torches and a *light* spell, which both have a range of 5. I see from the other question that there's no explicit rulings on this and I'll go to the chat to ask for opinions on my (slightly different) situation.

Comment: Also worth noting that if the enemies did not make a stealth check to become hidden or their check was lower than the highest passive perception in the party, you would know where they are / put their minis on the map even if they are not illuminated. Being out of the light source only gives them total concealment, but players still know their positions. Incidentally, walls always fail their stealth checks, so players always know the layout of all walls, even in the darkness!